# Putting legends within the frame of the plot at the desired position

Tags: graphics3d, legending

```
dat1krafull = {{1.`, 2.61594`*^-8}, {10.`, 7.10017`*^-9}, {50.`,
```

2.1565`*^-9}, {75.`, 1.6567`*^-9}, {100.`, 1.37786`*^-9}, {250.`, 
   7.500625`*^-10}, {500.`, 4.754925`*^-10}, {750.`, 
   3.612`*^-10}, {1000.`, 2.94925`*^-10}}

```
dat1kra = {{1.`, 2.8896`*^-10}, {10.`, 7.89039`*^-11}, {50.`, 
2.403665`*^-11}, {75.`, 1.8478`*^-11}, {100.`, 
1.53523`*^-11}, {250.`, 8.33675`*^-12}, {500.`, 
5.24605`*^-12}, {750.`, 3.95007`*^-12}, {1000.`, 3.19502`*^-12}}



pltkra2part = 
       ListLogLogPlot[ dat1kra, 
       PlotRange -> {{10^0, 10^3}, {10^-12, 10^-6}}, 
       Ticks -> {Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, 0, 3}], 
       Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -12, -6}]} , 
       Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.006], Line} , 
       FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.002], FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
       FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Black, 14], 
       PlotLegends -> {Style["KRA, |b| > 20 Degree, with cuts on r and 
       z", Bold, 12]} ,FrameLabel -> {Style["Energy (GeV)", Bold, 15],
        Style["Flux (GeV \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-2\)]\) \
        \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(-\\\ 1\)]\) \
         \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sr\), \(-1\)]\))", Bold, 15]}, Frame ->
          True, 
           ImageSize -> 500 ]

  pltkra1full = 
     ListLogLogPlot[ dat1krafull, 
     PlotRange -> {{10^0, 10^3}, {10^-12, 10^-6}}, 
     Ticks -> {Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, 0, 3}], 
     Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -12, -6}]} , 
     Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.006], Dashed} , 
     FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.002], FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Black, 14], 
     PlotLegends -> {Style[
     "KRA, |b| > 20 Degree, without cuts on r and z", Bold, 12]} , 
      FrameLabel -> {Style["Energy (GeV)", Bold, 15], 
      Style["Flux (GeV \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-2\)]\) \
       \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(s\), \(-\\\ 1\)]\) \
        \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sr\), \(-1\)]\))", Bold, 15]}, Frame -> 
         True, ImageSize -> 500 ] 
Show[pltkra1full, pltkra2part]
```

In the above, I put my codes two plot data. The main problem is that the legends in the plots are outside the frame. But I want the legends to be within the frame o the plot at my desired place. Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to extract the plots and  the legends from `pltkra1full` and `pltkra2part` (this easily done by taking `Part[pltkra1full, 1]` and `Part[pltkra1full, 2, 1, 1]`, respectively for `pltkra1full`, and similarly for `pltkra2part`) and use a combination of `Legended`, `Show` and `Placed` as follows:

```
Legended[Show[First @ pltkra1full, First @ pltkra2part], 
 Placed[Column@{pltkra1full[[2, 1, 1]], pltkra2part[[2, 1, 1]]}, {.65, .85}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine